# typescript: automatically create getters for all of a constructor's named parameters

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

To make constructor calls more readable, I generally prefer to use named parameters as follows:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(private args: {a: number, b: string, c: boolean}) {}
}

// Example constructor call:
const x = new MyClass({a: 1, b: "hello", c: true})
```

However, I also want `a`, `b`, and `c` to be publicly readable, i.e. I'd like to be able to call `x.a`, `x.b` and `x.c` rather than using `x.args.a`, `x.args.b`, and `x.args.c`. I can come up with a few different ways of doing this (see below), but they all involve repetitive boilerplate to explicitly create properties or getters.

Is there a way that I can create these getters automatically, e.g. by writing a decorator or using a generic?

**Approach 1: explicitly declare properties and populate them in the constructor**

This is pretty verbose!

```js
class MyClass1 {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: boolean;
  
  constructor(private args: {a: number, b: string, c: boolean}) { 
    this.a = args.a;
    this.b = args.b; 
    this.c = args.c;
  }
}
```

**Approach 2: store args and write getters**

More concise than Approach 1, but I'd love to have these getters created automatically.

```js
class MyClass2 {
  
  constructor(private args: {a: number, b: string, c: boolean}) {};

  get a(): number {return this.args.a}
  get b(): string {return this.args.b}
  get c(): boolean {return this.args.c}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With many thanks to Simon Jacobs [for this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65446858/239712) and the comment thread that followed, this seems to be the most concise approach:

```js
// type containing the properties (not methods) of a type T
type PropertiesFilter<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends ((...args: any) => any) ? never : K]: T[K]
}

abstract class NamedConstructorArgsBaseClass<T> {

  // Constructor takes an object with all the 
  // properties (not methods) of T
  constructor(args: PropertiesFilter<T>) {
    // Set all of those properties on the object being constructed
    Object.entries(args).forEach(
      eachNamedArg => (this as any)[eachNamedArg[0]] = eachNamedArg[1]
    )
  }

}

// in main program

class MyClassLogger extends NamedConstructorArgsBaseClass<MyClassLogger> {
  a: string;
  b: number;

  log() { 
    console.log(this.a, this.b);
  }
}

new MyClassLogger({a: "hi", b: 99}).log() // logs: hi, 99
```

Answer (score 2):

This does what you want using decorators:

```
// Decorator setup

interface IndexedObject { [name: string]: any }
type Constructor = new(...args: any[]) => IndexedObject

function namedConstructorArgs <T extends Constructor> (targetConstructor: T): T {
  return class proxyConstructor extends targetConstructor {
    constructor(...args: any[]){
      super(args)
      Object.entries(args[0]).forEach(
        eachNamedArg => this[ eachNamedArg[0] ] = eachNamedArg[1]
      )
    }
  }
}

// In main program

abstract class MyClassLoggerProperties {
  a: string
  b: number
}

@namedConstructorArgs
class MyClassLogger extends MyClassLoggerProperties {

  constructor(_: MyClassLoggerProperties) {
    super()
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  }

}

new MyClassLogger( { a: "i like flake number", b: 99 } )
  .log() // logs: I like flake number, 99
```

Note I had to turn off the `strictPropertyInitialization` compiler flag so the compiler accepts the properties of the class not being initialised in its own constructor. You could also initialise the properties to dummy values if you prefer to keep the compiler flag.

The abstract class is used to ensure the class properties in the statement of the class and in the constructor are the same as compiler won't check they are consistent otherwise. You could repeat the properties declaration in these places and omit the `super()` call in the constructor but it wouldn't be as type safe.

Comment: Very nice!!  I tried cutting out the step of writing the abstract class and then extending it -- afaict this works as long as there are no non-constructor methods on the class: https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8

Comment: I suppose there is no way around having two new types if you want the constructor argument to have a different type to the class itself. Maybe one other idea if you don't like the abstract/parent class, is you could define the constructor argument as a ```Pick``` type of the class (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys), picking the property names from the class that are supplied in the constructor

Comment: Ah, good point re: `Pick`: https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8#file-named_constructor_with_pick-ts  And `Omit` also works: https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8#file-named_constructor_with_omit-ts

If only there were a way to pick just properties and not methods...

Comment: Ah, but there is: see link below. That should work nicely if all non-methods are set in the constructor. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTge0nYBLCBnAYqgNsCOKAHigBUoA+KAXigG8AoKFqAbSgGkpUA7KANYQQCAGbkoAQwzk2nALpQIADwK8AJjIAUULQDoDkuAHMMALim8QASlrVJVqLYD8UXhABuhKBe7yLZHLyjAC+jIx8BHCikgDG0ACyqMoQ6gDyAEYAVhCxwAzMrBjAcHzG8EgWxaW8xoUsvACuALYZhBVgFk2thPVQCNm5wB0W9FJdLW1EYaxQzRDAABYI6e463RM9cAA0UNVVJWVOo-2NwGBnBzXGUDOs80srZADuCOstm1O7+3uHtbsDLInMCITr9QZ5W7HPYgVoIXChcKgSBQJIpdIQ4A4fCEVK0WCgwhoTDYqIkVHJVKZHKQyjhAD0ACooMjEpSMTSsXgoni6ExZtUyiNftc+t0psLxb1ZoChsKxpJPt4wmFGfSgA

Comment: So [this looks like a solution](https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8#file-named_constructor_with_properties_filter-ts)!

Comment: And we can save the user the trouble of writing out the constructor with an abstract class [like this](https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8#file-named_constructor_with_properties_filter_2-ts)

Comment: Hmm though it seems like then we should be able to put the decorator-applied constructor right in the base class...

Comment: Seems like this can work via abstract class with no decorator as long as I use one `as any`: https://gist.github.com/brahn/a93d8b5a5a0390a063d51e75251a0cb8#file-named_constructor_with_abstract_class-ts. @simon-jacobs wdyt?

Comment: Yes we'd originally told the decorator it would only get classes with index signatures by using the type ```IndexedObject``` in the decorator definition. If the assignment of each property in the ```forEach``` loop takes places on a concrete type, that type would need the same index signature – which is done by adding ```[name: string]: any``` to the class